# tr border isn't on the right side 100% heigh

Tags: html, css

Why is the border in the middle (between the tr's) not 100% heigh? How can i change it? Here is a demo:

```css
.one_tutorial{
    display: block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.one_tutorial_title{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.one_tutorial_info{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table> 
    <tr class="one_tutorial"> 
        <td class="one_tutorial_title">Wie bewässere ich meine Pflanzen</td> 
        <td class="one_tutorial_info">Geschrieben von ???, am 17.05.2015 um 14:07 Uhr</td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was the top/bottom padding of 5px;, here is your solution:

[Working:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w6jrdpu3/)

**CSS**

```
.one_tutorial_title{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;/*Changed to 10px from 5px*/
    width: 300px;
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.one_tutorial_info{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;/*Changed to 0px from 5px*/
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: But now the secound tr have no padding. How can i solve this problem? With a invisible emelemt? and the invisible element have a heigh of 5px?

Comment: hmmm im sorry. Your first answer was perfect, but i didnt noticed the padding... Im sorry, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove your changes for the `display` properties of your table elements if you apply `table-layout: fixed;` to your table. I assume you did this because of you table cells not properly respecting the widths you assigned to them?

Comment: Yes i want to give them a fixed width